# How can I exhibit a bijection between sets $A\times(B\times C)$ and $(A\times B)\times C$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am asked to prove that these two sets are equivalent, so I know I must find a bijection between the two of them. But how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Think: What would you map $(a,(b,c))$ to, where $a,b,c$ are elements of $A,B,C$ resspectively?

Comment: @ziggurism: The two set theory tags are meant to be disjoint.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see. Thanks for the headsup.

Answer (score 1):

The map $f\colon A\times(B\times C)\to (A\times B)\times C$ should take $(a,(b,c))$ to $((a,b),c)$, where $a\in A,$ $b\in B$, and $c\in C$.